# How can I install the latest full version of Canon ZoomBrowser EX without the original CD?

Tags: installation, camera

ZoomBrowser EX comes with Canon cameras.

Canon software enigeering team did a really poor job analyzing how people are using the software:

- people do lose their x-year old CD
- or do not have it with them when travelling
- do not have a CD drive at all (very common nowdays)

Canon updater from their website does not allow you to install the software if it does not find the original CD in the drive.

The question is how do I trick the installer to run on a computer and install the product that I payed for.

Currently the latest version is [6.5.1.15](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0037987.asp?model) and you can download the **updater** from Canon website. In fact the updater is just the full installer but it doesn't allow you to install if it doesn't find a previous install or the original CD.

Note: In the past I used to save a registry file with registry keys used by it, loading it did allowed me to run the installer but now, with Windows 7 x64 it seams that it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this a while ago.. My Mom's CD Rom Drive died.  I installed [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) on the computer, and she is much happier with it.  It handles importing the pictures and videos much better than the canon software.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fix by adding registry files which trick it into thinking that the old version was installed. Once you've done that, the updater will work perfectly, as it's actually a complete installation.

[Guide](http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/article_pages/install_canon_software.html)